# JSON API group and subgroup EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

So I want to build the following select dropdown in ember, using ember data and the API is going to be using the JSON API spec. Here is a screenshot example
[image: Select Dropdown]

So would I in the services model, state the following

app/model/service.js

```
category: DS.belongsTo('category'),
subCategory: DS.belongsTo('sub-category')
```

app/model/category.js

```
service: DS.hasMany('service'),
subCategory: DS.belongsTo('category')
```

app/model/category.js

```
service: DS.hasMany('service'),
category: DS.belongsTo('sub-category')
```

I feel like I am missing something? Thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I think want you're missing is this:

```
export DS.Model.extend({
  parent: DS.belongsTo('category', { inverse: 'children'}),
  children: DS.hasMany('category', { inverse: 'parent' }),
});
```

this will allow you to have a parent/child relationship with one model. If you want a different model for the sub-category I don't really understand whats your problem is.